# Set selected time in EKEvent

Tags: ios, swift, reminders, ekevent

In my application I can select date and time for `EKEvent`. I almost achieved what I want except Time. How can I set time. Below is my code, I have tried.

```
func setReminder(){
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    eventStore.requestAccess(
        to: EKEntityType.event, completion: {(granted, error) in
            if !granted {
                print("Access to store not granted")
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("Access granted")

                let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

                event.title = self.getCategoryText + " Reminder"
                event.calendar =
                    eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                event.timeZone = TimeZone.current
                let alarm = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: self.selectedDate!)
                event.addAlarm(alarm)

                if self.daysBeforeDate != nil{
                    let earlierDate = self.daysBeforeDate
                    let earlierAlarm = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: earlierDate!)
                    event.addAlarm(earlierAlarm)
                }

                print("selected time", self.selectedTime)

                var number1: Double = (self.selectedTime! as NSString).doubleValue

                event.startDate = self.selectedDate!.addingTimeInterval(number1)
                event.endDate = self.selectedDate!

                do {
                    try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
                } catch let error  {
                    print("Reminder failed with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

            }
    })

}
```

**Update 1**

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

  var dateComponents = DateComponents()
  dateComponents.year = calendar.component(.year, from: self.selectedDate!)
  dateComponents.month = calendar.component(.month, from: self.selectedDate!)
  dateComponents.day = calendar.component(.day, from: self.selectedDate!)
  dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone.current
  dateComponents.hour = self.selectedHour
  dateComponents.minute = self.selectedMinute

  let userCalendar = Calendar.current // user calendar
  let someDateTime = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)
```

Comment: Try `event.startDate = self.selectedDate!.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(number1))` also make endDate greater than startDate

Comment: @Mukesh thanks for reply, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I've used for creating an event for a time interval and it's working fine for me:

```
func saveEvent(on date: Date, withTitle title: String, forHourse hourse: Int) {
    let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore!)
    event.title = title
    event.startDate = date
    event.endDate = date.addingTimeInterval((TimeInterval(hourse * 60 * 60)))
    let alarm = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: date)
    event.alarms = [alarm]
    event.calendar = (eventStore?.defaultCalendarForNewEvents)!

    do {
        try eventStore?.save(event, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
    } catch {

    }
}
```

Comment: I have a time picker so user can select any time, i have to set only user selected time

Comment: So create a `Date` object with user selected time and set it as `event.startDate`.

Comment: Created, getting 2191-08-11 07:34:00 +0000. Do I need to add time zone??

Comment: No your date's year is 2191 which is not correct you're doing something wrong creating date.

Comment: Do you want to create the event for today's date?